# Are there any protocols/standards on top of TCP optimized for high throughput and low latency?

Tags: language-agnostic, tcp, protocols

Are there any protocols/standards that work over TCP that are optimized for high throughput and low latency?

The only one I can think of is [FAST](http://www.fixprotocol.org/fast).

At the moment I have devised just a simple text-based protocol delimited by special characters.  I'd like to adopt a protocol which is designed for fast transfer and supports perhaps compression and minification of the data that travels over the TCP socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service).  JMS can run on top of TCP, and you can get reasonable latency with a message broker like [ActiveMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveMQ).

It really depends on your target audience though.  If your building a game which must run anywhere, you pretty much need to use HTTP or HTTP/Streaming.  If you are pushing around market data on a LAN, than something NOT using TCP would probably suite you better.  [Tibco RV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibco_Software) and [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) both provide reliable low-latency messaging over multicast.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using heavy-weight TCP, we can utilize the connection-oriented/reliable feature of TCP on the top of UDP by any of the following way:

1. [UDP-based Data Transfer Protocol(UDT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP-based_Data_Transfer_Protocol):
   UDT is built on top of User Datagram Protocol (UDP) by adding congestion control and reliability control mechanisms. UDT is an application level, connection oriented, duplex protocol that supports both reliable data streaming and partial reliable messaging.

   Acknowledgment:
   UDT uses periodic acknowledgments (ACK) to confirm packet delivery, while negative ACKs (loss reports) are used to report packet loss. Periodic ACKs help to reduce control traffic on the reverse path when the data transfer speed is high, because in these situations, the number of ACKs is proportional to time, rather than the number of data packets.
2. Reliable User Datagram Protocol (RUDP):
   It aims to provide a solution where UDP is too primitive because guaranteed-order packet delivery is desirable, but TCP adds too much complexity/overhead.

   It extends UDP by adding the following additional features:

   1. Acknowledgment of received packets
   2. Windowing and congestion control
   3. Retransmission of lost packets
   4. Overbuffering (Faster than real-time streaming)

   en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol

Answer (score 2):

If layered on top of TCP, you won't get better throughput or latency than the 'barest' TCP connection.

there are other non-TCP high-throughput and/or low-latency connection-oriented protocols, usually layered on top of UDP.

almost the only one i know is [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/), which is optimized for networks where the high bandwidth or long round trip times (RTT) makes typical TCP retransmissions suboptimal.  These are called 'extremely long fat networks' ([LFN, pronounced 'elefan'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product)).

Answer (score 1):

Just as you mentioned FAST - it is intended for market data distribution and is used by leading stock exchanges and is running on the top of UDP multicast.

In general, with current level of networks reliability it always worth putting your protocol on the top of UDP.
Whatever having session sequence number, NACK+server-to-client-heartbeat and binary marshalling should be close to theoretical performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin/root privilege on the sending side, you can also try a TCP acceleration driver like SuperTCP.